# Is it possible to get LAST_INSERT_ID() from different database?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, last-insert-id

Suppose, that we have 2 databases: `a` and `b`, and tables `a.test1` and `b.test2`.

If I need to insert a row into table `a.test1`, and return `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to insert into `b.test2`, will `LAST_INSERT_ID()` return value from another database? Is it reliable?

I didn't find anything in the manual, but `@@IDENTITY` depends on client session, so it should be portable between two databases. Isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` always gives you the id of the row inserted by the last `INSERT` statement you executed on the current connection, irrespective of what table (and what database!) that row went into.

Comment: So, it depends on connection, not on database? Thanks, I'll accept your answer, when I'll be able to.

Answer (score 2):

**From Mysql documentation**:The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that client. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own. This behavior ensures that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or transactions.

Inshort Both *LAST_INSERT_ID()* and *mysql_insert_id()* work as advertised i.e.: they will retrieve the last id inserted into any table during the current session/connection.